# Browser still redirect to https instead of http after removing SSL certificate

Tags: http, ssl, dns, hosting, namecheap

I hosted a website with my personal profile and information last year. I bought the domain, hosting, and SSL certificate(which was free) from namecheap. Now two weeks ago, I have renewed the domain and hosting plans, but did not buy/renew the SSL certificate since I thought its a waste of money for a simple personal profile without any user information. But, the problem was since SSL was expired browsers were stopping me to access the site (however, I can access it in Advanced Mode). Then, I removed the expired SSL certificate from my cPanel of namecheap. Now, my site can be accessed if I use HTTP, but cannot access HTTPS, which is fine. But, when I put *myname.org* in the browsers' URL, they redirect it to *https://myname.org* and thus broswers block my website but I don't need https, I want it to open as "http://myname.org".

In summary:

I can access my site when I write. [www.myname.org](http://www.myname.org)  or http://myname.org but cannot access https://myname.org
Now, how to restrict browsers to use https:// for my website, I want broswers to use unsecure http:// . I think I can do something in cPanel so that browsers use http instead of https for my website. I think namecheap somehow forcing my site to use https, so that I renew their ssl certificate. But I don't want to use or renew SSL certificate. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There are not enough details given, specifically no way to reproduce what you are writing since the domain is enough. But the problem you describe is common when a permanent redirect  was added to HTTPS and later HTTPS was disabled. The permanent redirect is still cached in the browsers which visited the site though, so they will ignore whatever your site does not since they already know that they should redirect to HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to update the mod_rewrite code by following

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: It is not working. I copy pasted this code in .htaccess but when I try to put https before domain name it does not redirect to http